# Как вытянуть значение регуляркой из String?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
String value = "Value 20 mg; 10 pack x 5 x 2 items = $500.30";
```

Нужно вытянуть значение после второго `x` (то есть 2).

1. До первого `x` может быть любое значение (например: видеокарта, процессор и тд.)
2. После первого `x` всегда целочисленные цифры, также после второго `x`. `Items` не изменяется.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, не знаю, как именно это делается в Java, но в JavaScript работает следующий вариант:

```
pattern = /.*?x (\d*) items/
var string = "The x man 20 mg; 10 pack x 533 x 212 items = $500.30"
string.match(pattern)[1]
```

Само регулярное выражение должно работать одинаково.

Comment: Думаю, после того `x` всегда что-то будет поэтому точнее будет не `\d*`, а `\d+`

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```
String value = "Value 20 mg; 10 pack x 5 x 2 items = $500.30";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?x (\\d+) items");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // 2
}
```

Comment: cпасибо, подошло

Comment: @user318390, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)